# Como puedo hacer que un <button> cargué de nuevo la pagina en JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera agregar la funcionalidad de refrescar la pagina al boton id"refresh" en JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <title>Wordle PPY</title>
</head> 
<body>
<button id="refresh">Jugar de nuevo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que aprendas como funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu segunda medalla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const refresh = document.getElementById('refresh');

refresh.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  console.log('Recargando...')
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<button id="refresh">Jugar de nuevo</button>
```